# How to return a boolean value from a regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong here..

```
if @calc.docket_num =~ /DC-000044-10/ || @calc.docket_num =~ /DC-67-09/
  @calc.lda = true
else
  @calc.lda = false
end
```

But it seems that `@calc.docket_num` can be any string whatsoever and it always returns as `true`.

Am I not doing this right?

Comment: When testing your code, it actually returns "nil" (equivalent to "false" for the sake of the if/else statement) for any value other than "DC-000044-10" or "DC-67-09"...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a one-liner:

```
@calc.lda = !!(@calc.docket_num =~ /DC-000044-10|DC-67-09/)
```

The `!!` forces the response to true/false, then you can assign your boolean variable directly.

Comment: +1 for use of `!!`. The regex could be a bit tighter though: `/DC-(?:000044-10|67-09)/`

Comment: Awesome. Never knew about `!!`.

Comment: I just googled the same question and found my own question from a year ago and found your answer which is hella amazing. Many thanks.

Comment: @Trip You know you *can* change the answer you've accepted as best... :)

Comment: Hahaha, Mark you're a tough salesman. No, but seriously, only because I use this as a core part of my prgramming now. Thanks again Mark!

Comment: Regarding the "tighter" regex: just because you can, doesn't mean you *should*. This is not regex golf. The documentation value of having full docket numbers listed far outweighs the savings of a couple characters.

Comment: 100% Agree with Mark.  Very wise advice.  Regex can be very error-prone so it's a much better choice in terms of maintainability and readability to make it as simple to understand as possible, and that means more explicit values.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you could use the triple equals (`===`) operator for the Regexp class which is used for determining equality when using `case` syntax.

```
@calc.lda = /DC-000044-10|DC-67-09/ === @calc.docket_num 
@calc.lda
=> true
```

**BEWARE**

`/Regexp/ === String` is totally different than `String === /Regexp/`!!!!  The method is not commutative.  Each class implements `===` differently.  For the question above, the regular expression has to be to the left of `===`.

For the Regexp implementation, you can see more documentation on this (as of Ruby 2.2.1) [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D).

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is somewhere else in your implementation.  Use this code to check it:

```
k = 'random information'

if k =~ /DC-000044-10/ || k =~ /DC-67-09/
  puts 'success'
else
  puts 'failure'
end

=> failure
```

Comment: This can be shortened using the ternary operator: `puts (k =~ /DC-(?000044-10|67-09)/) ? 'success' : 'failure'`