# How to Build regular expression pattern in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, haml

I am actually writing rails code where i want to check if

`params[:name]` = any character like `= , / \`

to return true or return false otherwise.

How do i build a regex pattern for this or if any other better way exists would help too .

Answer (score 0):

```
sanitized = params[:name].scan(/[=,\/\\]/)
if sanitized.empty?
  # No such character in params[:name]
else
  # oops, found atleast 1
end
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's achieved the status of "idiomatic", but I think the most compact way of achieving this in Ruby is with double `!`:

```
!!(params[:name] =~ /[=,\/\\]/)
```

as discussed in [How to return a boolean value from a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858415/how-to-return-a-boolean-value-from-a-regex)